# Register C function in Lua table

Tags: c++, lua, lua-c++-connection

How to register a C function in Lua, but not in a global context, but as a table field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void register_c_function(char const * const tableName, char const * const funcName, CFunctionSignature funcPointer)
{
    lua_getfield(lstate, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, tableName);  // push table onto stack
    if (!lua_istable(lstate, -1))                       // not a table, create it
    {
        lua_createtable(lstate, 0, 1);      // create new table
        lua_setfield(lstate, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, tableName);  // add it to global context

        // reset table on stack
        lua_pop(lstate, 1);                 // pop table (nil value) from stack
        lua_getfield(lstate, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, tableName);  // push table onto stack
    }

    lua_pushstring(lstate, funcName);       // push key onto stack
    lua_pushcfunction(lstate, funcPointer); // push value onto stack
    lua_settable(lstate, -3);               // add key-value pair to table

    lua_pop(lstate, 1);                     // pop table from stack
}
```

Comment: Why not just use luaL_register?

Answer (score 21):

This is what [`luaL_register()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_register) is intended to do, for one or more functions. The canonical usage is as part of the setup for a module written in C:

```
/* actual definitions of modA() and modB() are left as an exercise. */

/* list of functions in the module */
static const luaL_reg modfuncs[] =
{
    { "a", modA},
    { "b", modB},
    { NULL, NULL }
};

/* module loader function called eventually by require"mod" */  
int luaopen_mod(lua_State *L) {
    luaL_register(L, "mod", modfuncs);
    return 1;
}
```

where this creates a module named "mod" that has two functions named `mod.a` and `mod.b`.

Quoting the manual for `luaL_register(L,libname,l)`:

> When called with `libname` equal to
>   `NULL`, it simply registers all
>   functions in the list `l` (see [`luaL_Reg`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_Reg))
>   into the table on the top of the
>   stack.
>
> When called with a non-null `libname`,
>   `luaL_register` creates a new table `t`,
>   sets it as the value of the global
>   variable `libname`, sets it as the value
>   of `package.loaded[libname]`, and
>   registers on it all functions in the
>   list `l`. If there is a table in
>   `package.loaded[libname]` or in variable
>   `libname`, reuses this table instead of
>   creating a new one.
>
> In any case the function leaves the table on the top of the stack.

`luaL_register()` can be used to put C functions in any table by passing `NULL` for its second parameter as long as the table is on the top of the stack.

Comment: If there is already mod table with other fields, will it be extended or replaced with new one after luaL_register() call?

Comment: it will reuse and update a previous table, according to the 5.1 manual.

Comment: Whether applied to a named global table or the table at the top of stack, it only sets those fields named in the list of functions to register and leaves any other fields untouched. The difference is that given a global name, it also creates the table if needed and adds a reference to `package.loaded`.

Comment: I do not like that a client code knows luaL_reg type. I prefer to incapsulate such things. See my solution.

Comment: FYI... luaL_Register has been deprecated in 5.2 .. luaL_newlib and luaL_setfuncs seems to be the replacement.